# Unable to send emails on Tomcat 5.5 using Apache Commons Email

Tags: java, apache-commons, tomcat5.5

I am using Apache Commons Email to send out the emails from our web application. Everything works fine on the JBOSS server. Emails are sent out properly.

When I deploy the same application on the tomcat the emails don't go.

Below is the error that i get on tomcat 5.5

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
com.demoproject.interceptors.MenuInterceptor.intercept(MenuInterceptor.java:30)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:50)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.demoproject.interceptors.AuthInterceptor.intercept(AuthInterceptor.java:45)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
```

Below is the code that I am using to send the email.

```
String host = ............;
String port = .............;
String username = ............;
String password = ............;
String fromName = ............;
String fromAddress = ............;

try {
  SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();

  email.sethost(host);

  if (username != null && username.length() > 0
        && password != null && password.length() > 0) {
// control comes here but following line is never executed
    email.setAuthentication(username, password); 
  }

  if (port != null && port.length() > 0) {
    email.setport(Integer.parseInt(port));
  }

  email.addTo(toAddress, toName);
  email.setFrom(fromAddress, fromName);
  email.setSubject(subject);
  email.setMsg(message);
  email.send();
  } catch (EmailException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: please print a full stack trace, this one just tells that the error occurred in a method invoked through reflection

Comment: @Riccardo Cossu I have updated my question with the full stack trace. I hope it helps.

Comment: That's still not the full trace. The interesting bit is below that.

Comment: he's using the infamous e.printStackTrace(), there will never be trace of what's useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add mail.jar to the lib directory of tomcat. It should solve your problem as it has solved mine.